# How to understand "unhealthy" status of airflow container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, airflow

I am starting am airflow docker-compose as per official recommendation [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.1.2/docker-compose.yaml)
but with my own Dokerfile, which is simple:

```
FROM apache/airflow:2.1.0
RUN pip install apache-airflow-providers-docker==1.2.0
```

When I do it for the first time:
[image]

If I restart containers, then all of them are unhealthy. Also if I run `docker-compose up airflow-init` for the second time it freezes.

Also DAG, which I see in the userinterface does not get updated, when I change it on my side. If I am trying to go inside of the container airflow-worker and check `ls /dags` bash freezes.

To be able to run everything again I have to restart the whole Docker

Comment: Hello! Similar issue with Win10 and wsl. Docker desktop is running, Ubuntu on wsl is working, I also used `docker-compose --build` just before airflow up. Which is your system?

Comment: Hi, I am on Mac. Try to follow all steps on their website including `mkdir ./dags ./logs ./plugins
echo -e "AIRFLOW_UID=$(id -u)\nAIRFLOW_GID=0" > .env` I don't know but it works then :) but still unhealthy, but works)) https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/docker.html

Comment: exactly, for me the situation is the same, i have custom Dockerfile and so the state is unhealthy..but would be cool to know how to understand what is unhealthy :)